# Openldap Spring integration: Bad Credentials

Tags: spring, ldap

I have openldap running on OSX (although will be moving to centos running IPA when going to production).

Simple spring boot application with nothing in it other than a single home controller, spring security and the ldap starters.  Pom dependencies are as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
    <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

As well as the dependencies above I have a configuration class as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and().formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=users")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource(contextSource())
            .passwordCompare()
            .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
            .passwordAttribute("userPassword");      
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
            return  new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(Arrays.asList("ldap://localhost:389/"), "dc=m,dc=com");
    }
}
```

My LDAP directory is very simple, it has the following:

```
# m.com
dn: dc=m,dc=com
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: M
dc: m

# users, m.com
dn: ou=users,dc=m,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: users

# taylorj, users, m.com
dn: uid=taylorj,ou=users,dc=m,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
cn: Jonathan Taylor
uid: taylorj
uidNumber: 1
gidNumber: 1
homeDirectory: /home/taylorj
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9UVNVNDBOdlh1bkJqNkhGeVUwekVVYXlNb2RidTErekg=
```

When I run the spring application, it makes the connection to LDAP, I can see the reuests coming in on the LDAP server, I can see it search OK and return a result then do a CMP on the userPassword attribute, however, LDAP then returns an error code 5 (LDAP_COMPARE_FALSE) and in spring I see the following exception:

```
2017-09-13 15:52:13.315 DEBUG 92002 --- [nio-8132-exec-3] o.s.s.l.a.LdapAuthenticationProvider     : Processing authentication request for user: taylorj
2017-09-13 15:52:13.317 DEBUG 92002 --- [nio-8132-exec-3] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findResources(jndi.properties)
2017-09-13 15:52:13.330 DEBUG 92002 --- [nio-8132-exec-3] o.s.l.c.support.AbstractContextSource    : Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://localhost:389/dc=m,dc=com'
2017-09-13 15:52:13.339 DEBUG 92002 --- [nio-8132-exec-3] .s.s.l.a.PasswordComparisonAuthenticator : Performing LDAP compare of password attribute 'userPassword' for user 'uid=taylorj,ou=users'
2017-09-13 15:52:13.340 DEBUG 92002 --- [nio-8132-exec-3] o.s.l.c.support.AbstractContextSource    : Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://localhost:389/dc=m,dc=com'
2017-09-13 15:52:13.342 DEBUG 92002 --- [nio-8132-exec-3] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
2017-09-13 15:52:13.342 DEBUG 92002 --- [nio-8132-exec-3] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials

org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.PasswordComparisonAuthenticator.authenticate(PasswordComparisonAuthenticator.java:114) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong as it seems to be some sort of internal spring thing going on that is causing the password comparison to fail.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I reverted back to an LDIF that spring provides, and that worked fine.  Frustrated, I then ran the following to change the password of the user ben provided by spring LDIF

ldappasswd -x -D "cn=admin,dc=m,dc=com" -W -S "uid=ben,ou=people,dc=m,dc=com"

After running this command, my login no longer works

Looking at the LDIF provided by Spring:

```
dn: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=m,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Ben Alex
sn: Alex
uid: ben
userPassword: {SHA}nFCebWjxfaLbHHG1Qk5UU4trbvQ=
```

It seems to be setting the password as a SHA, whereas when I run ldappasswd it ends up as a Salted SHA {SSHA}.  As far as I can see from documentation, the spring implementation should handle both SHA and SSHA though.

Still not sure what is going on though.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, spring-security has a bug.

org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication. PasswordComparisonAuthenticator

initial lines of setPasswordEncoder method:

```
public void setPasswordEncoder(Object passwordEncoder) {
    if (passwordEncoder instanceof PasswordEncoder) {
        this.usePasswordAttrCompare = false;
        setPasswordEncoder((PasswordEncoder) passwordEncoder);
        return;
    }
```

In this it sets `usePasswordAttrCompare` to **false** if the password encoder is of type PasswordEncoder.  The problem with this is that when this flag is set to **false** it falls back to getting LDAP to do the password comparison.  Since the passwords are stored as SSHA, Spring has no way of knowing the SHA Salt in advance and therefore just sends a SHA1 version of the password, which obviously doesn't match.

In authenticate()

```
else if (isLdapPasswordCompare(user, ldapTemplate, password)) {
        return user;
}
```

Due to the way the LdapShaPasswordEncoder is implemented, the encode function takes just the plaintext password, whereas the isPasswordValid takes both the plaintext password and the hashed password for comparison and can therefore calculate the SSHA variant by extracting the salt.

I modified (I will go back and do it properly at some point) the `setPasswordEncoder` function as follows:

```
if (passwordEncoder instanceof PasswordEncoder) {
    if(passwordEncoder instanceof org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.LdapShaPasswordEncoder) {
        this.usePasswordAttrCompare = true;
    } else {
        this.usePasswordAttrCompare = false;
    }
    setPasswordEncoder((PasswordEncoder) passwordEncoder);
    return;
}
```

In the case where we have a LdapShaPasswordEncoder we will always fall back to the isPasswordValid method which handles plaintext, SHA and SSHA passwords.

Having rebuilt spring-security and rebuilt my code against the new jars it works fine.  Now to figure out a nicer way to do it and submit it to Spring to pull.

Comment: Great stuff Jon.